# All buttons are of same color, they should not be

Tags: java, android

I am working on simple color picker in Android. I've setup [Android Array String Resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource) for colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="color_picker_palette">
        <item>#fff44336</item>
        <item>#ffe91e63</item>
        <item>#ff9c27b0</item>
        <item>#ff673ab7</item>
        <item>#ff3f51b5</item>
        <item>#ff2196f3</item>
        <item>#ff03a9f4</item>
        <item>#ff00bcd4</item>
        <item>#ff009688</item>
        <item>#ff4caf50</item>
        <item>#ff8bc34a</item>
        <item>#ffcddc39</item>
        <item>#ffffeb3b</item>
        <item>#ffffc107</item>
        <item>#ffff9800</item>
        <item>#ffff5722</item>
        <item>#ff795548</item>
        <item>#ff9e9e9e</item>
        <item>#ff607d8b</item>
        <item>#ffbcaaa4</item>
        <item>#ffeeeeee</item>
        <item>#ffb0bec5</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I import these colors through my `populateFetchedColors()` method:

```
private void populateFetchedColors()
{
    String[] colorsArray=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.color_picker_palette);

    if(fetchedColors==null)
    {
        this.fetchedColors=new ArrayList<ColorPickerFragmentAdapterRecord>();
    }
    else
    {
        this.fetchedColors.clear();
    }

    for(int colorIndex=0; colorIndex<colorsArray.length-1; colorIndex++)
    {
        ColorPickerFragmentAdapterRecord colorRecord=new ColorPickerFragmentAdapterRecord(colorsArray[colorIndex]);

        this.fetchedColors.add(colorRecord);
    }
}
```

which workss fine, I've double checked via [Android Studio Debugger](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug). Now, I had to create custom [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter), named `ColorPickerFragmentAdapter`:

```
package com.example.exmapleapp1.colorpicker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.example.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ColorPickerFragmentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ColorPickerFragmentAdapterRecord> implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private final ArrayList<ColorPickerFragmentAdapterRecord> dataSource;
    private final Context adapterContext;

    private static class ViewHolder
    {
        Button coloredButton;
    }

    public ColorPickerFragmentAdapter(@NonNull Context context,
                                      int resource,
                                      @NonNull ArrayList<ColorPickerFragmentAdapterRecord> objects)
    {
        super(context,
                resource,
                objects);

        this.adapterContext=context;
        this.dataSource=objects;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,
                        View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ColorPickerFragmentAdapterRecord item=this.getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext());

            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_picker_delegate_layout,
                    parent,
                    false);
            viewHolder.coloredButton=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.coloredButton);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.coloredButton.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(item.getColorName()));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

When I run this whole app, my buttons are listed just fine, however, they are all of same color, which it can be seen from screenshot:
[image: Color Picker Screenshot]
What did I miss?

Comment: try to display the value of `item.getColorName()` in Log and see what you will get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn, I've set the wrong adapter:

```
this.colorsGridView.setAdapter(this.fetchedColorsAdapter);
```

is wrong, the real `ArrayAdapter` used is:

```
this.colorsGridView.setAdapter(this.dataSource);
```

And I've also changed colors to `#rrggbb` format, I had `#aarrggbb` format in `colors_palette.xml` as you can see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="color_picker_palette">
        <item>#f44336</item>
        <item>#e91e63</item>
        <item>#9c27b0</item>
        <item>#673ab7</item>
        <item>#3f51b5</item>
        <item>#2196f3</item>
        <item>#03a9f4</item>
        <item>#00bcd4</item>
        <item>#009688</item>
        <item>#4caf50</item>
        <item>#8bc34a</item>
        <item>#cddc39</item>
        <item>#ffeb3b</item>
        <item>#ffc107</item>
        <item>#ff9800</item>
        <item>#ff5722</item>
        <item>#795548</item>
        <item>#9e9e9e</item>
        <item>#607d8b</item>
        <item>#bcaaa4</item>
        <item>#eeeeee</item>
        <item>#b0bec5</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and changed parsing of color to:

```
viewHolder.coloredButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(item.getColorName()));
```

Now it works:
[image: Correct way]

Answer (score 0):

Hej KernelPanic,

`setBackgroundColor` requires a ColorInt. I think instead of `Integer.parseInt(color)` you must call [item.getColorName().toColorInt()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/graphics/package-summary#(kotlin.String).toColorInt())